# How to prevent focus from going to browser links?

Tags: javascript, events, focus, blur

```
gestCookiesBtn.addEventListener('blur', function () {
   // prevent focus from going to browser links 
});
```

The idea is to prevent focus from going to browser links when event blur occurs on a specified button.  If you have any possible solutions, thank you in advance.